# Abbrev with different tables

Tags: abbrev

I am trying to use `abbrev-mode` but having great difficulty how to make it work for me.

I want to have different replacement tables that I can use for abbrev.

```
(setq word-table-2 
   '( ("all" . "l")     ("as" . "as")      ("can" . "k")
      ("do" . "do")     ("for" . "f")      ("in" . "n")
      ("is" . "s")      ("it" . "t")       ("know" . "no")
      ("like" . "lk")   ("little" . "ll")  ("more" . "mo")
      ("some" . "so")   ("than" . "n")     ("that" . "ta")
      ("there" . "tr")  ("this" . "th")    ("time" . "ti")
      ("to" . "to")     ("we" . "w")       ("well" . "l")
      ("will" . "l")    ("work" . "wk")    ("you" . "u") ))

(setq word-table-3
   '( ("again" . "ag")  ("any" . "n")    ("before" . "bf")
      ("every" . "ev")  ("from" . "fm")  ("good" . "g")
      ("here" . "he")   ("long" . "lg")  ("not" . "n")
      ("such" . "sc")   ("the" . "t")    ("would" . "d")
      ("year" . "y") ))
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about when and why you want each of these? IOW, what differentiates the times when you want to go from abbrev to word and the times when you want to go vice versa?

Comment: It should be a user command option that decides what table to use.

Comment: Do not assume that the tables that the `abbrev` mechanism uses are of the form you show above: they are not.

Comment: No. But one could select a list above and transfer convert it appropriately to form needed by abbrev.

Comment: How scheme could I use to setup abbrev from one table to another?